# Intent to start activity - but don't bring to front

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

Description:

- Activity **A** is visible (or in the background)
- Intent **I** is received by a broadcast with valuable extras and then passes the extras to a new Intent **I2** that will be used to start activity **A**.
- Outcome: **Do not bring** activity to front *if* activity is in background.

Code:

```
Intent I2= new Intent(context, MyActivity.class); 
I2.putExtra(..
I2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK); // | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
context.startActivity(I2);
```

Note: I added no "android:taskAffinity" to manifest.. i thought you should know

Comment: why do you want to startActivity when you don't want it to be in foreground,..? what is that you want to do..?

Comment: So I updated it: DO NOT BRING activity to front IF activity is in background!

Comment: Don't use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` for this! If you end up starting multiple tasks you will have a very hard time managing them. This is a can of worms that you do not want to open!

Answer (score 15):

if you want your activity to be in background add this line in the oncreate of activity

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Comment: How to make it works for `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` ? (2 tab button A and B, but should make it hide the app by any button's task instead of button B back to button A single direction) (`FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME` also single direction.)

Comment: [UPDATE] I can use global reference for first activity and make it `act.moveTaskToBack(true);` .

Comment: This should be an answer. @林果皞. I will try it now and see if ti is still valid.

Comment: This leads showing white screen very short time and hide it, isn't there any solution to open the activity totally in background without showing anything at all?

Answer (score 7):

You can use this line in your `onCreate()` method:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Comment: can you tell me how can i restart activity after call `moveTaskToBack(true);`
i used `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` but not restart the activity its make new one .. note** i instance same activity many times

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to start an `Activity` in the background. There are better ways to do what you want. You can have your `Activity` register to receive the broadcast `Intent`, for example. It will get the call to `onReceive()` even if it is in the background. You can determine if your `Activity` is in the background by setting a variable to `true` in `onPause()` and to `false` in `onResume()`. Then in `onReceive()`, if the variable is `true` you are in the background.

Comment: The question here is not how to check the current status of the activity, but how to prevent bringing back the application when it is in the background with the Intent still being sent.

Comment: @DamonYuan You can't do that. If you launch an `Intent` **for an `Activity`**, the task hosting that `Activity` will be brought fo the foreground. That's the way it works. You cannot get around that. What you **can do** is to use a different mechanism to get the behaviour you want (like `BroadcastReceiver`, which will **NOT cause the hosting task to be brought to the foreground.**

Comment: That's my understand. So your original answer is not the one to this question, but your comment above is the right one.