# Keeping specific activity on top of a backstack

Tags: android, android-activity

In our app we use an activity C from a library which always should be on the top of a back stack (or should always be visible in case if being on top is impossible).

For example we have an activity A where some asynchronous job is in progress. At some moment the activity C is launched so the backstack looks like this: A -> C. When the asynchronous job in A is done it should launch the activity B in such a way that C would still be visible but B would still exist. It looks like the back stack should be like A -> B -> C or (this looks more possible) there should be two back stacks like this: (A -> B) and (C).

For now we tried some manipulations with overriding `startActivity` for activity A.

Are there any better ways to achieve the situation that C should be always visible until a user closes the activity?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008879/intent-to-start-activity-but-dont-bring-to-front

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The SO answer doesn't work for me anyway but that Android doc was useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the answer. In case you encounter this stuff as well the solution in my case looked like this:

The idea is that I save the state in the activity A after the asynchronous work which is necessary for launching the activity B. If the activity C is on top of the stack, the activity B would not be launched (done via overriding A's `startActivity` method). Then when the activity C is finished, activity A’s `onStart` method is launched. And in this method we start Activity B. Visually it looks like what I wanted to achieve.